# Error: Parse error on line 17: Unexpected 'INDENT'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript, stripe-payments

I think I have an issue with my coffeescript. I'm following the stripe billing railcast but I get the following error:

Error: Parse error on line 17: Unexpected 'INDENT'

My coffeescript is this

```
$ ->
    $('.post').hover (event) ->
        $(this).toggleClass("hover")

  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_payment').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
        payment.processCard()
        false

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, payment.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      alert(response.id)
    else
      alert(response.error.message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra indentation on two lines in `payment.setupForm`.

Replace:

```
payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_payment').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
        payment.processCard() # <---------------------- Here
        false # <-------------------------------------- Here
```

with:

```
payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_payment').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      payment.processCard()
      false
```